# Simple Injector & Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, simple-injector

I'm sure that this questions has been asked several times, but I'm stuck in a rut on this one. I am attempting to automap properties from EF objects to defined interfaces. I'm using simple injector as my choice of IOC framework. (win forms)

I've registered my interfaces within the program.cs ..

```
container = new Container();
container.Register<IBob, Bob>();
...
```

and pass an instance of the container into the class where I'm doing the automapping ...

```
public ModelService(IDataRepository repo, Container container)       
{
    // create a reference to the repository
    this.Repository = repo;
    
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        // pass the reference into the constructor service.
        qcfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => container.GetInstance(type));
    
             cfg.AddProfile<ModelConfig>();
        });
    
        mapper = new Mapper(config);
    
}
```

The profile class looks a little bit like this ...

```
public class ModelConfig : Profile
{
    public ModelsConfig()
    {
                // mapping definition for product buy
                this.CreateMap<Entity.BobEF, IBob>()
                    .ForMember(destination => destination.UniqueIdentifier, option => option.MapFrom(source => source.BobID))
                    .ReverseMap();
                
}
```

So I was expecting automapper to use the container to create a concrete class for IBob given that this has already been declared within the BI bootstrapping and it should be using the "container.GetInstance()" method to resolve the interface, however what I'm actually getting in a proxy representation of the IBob class with a type of Proxy_MyProject.IBob_232342

I really don't understand the [automapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) for this as I'm new to using automapper.

Any HELP very much appreciated.

Regards,

Tim

**Edit**: (Example of model classes being used)

```
// shows the basic interface for a product
public interface IProduct : IModel
{

       string Name { get; set; }

       ISupplier Supplier { get; set; }

}

// shows the concrete implementation including the 
// exposed property being of type ISupplier 
public class Product : Model, IProduct
{
     public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

     public ISupplier Supplier
        {
            get;
            set;
        }   
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html#as

Answer (score 3):

`ConstructServicesUsing` *by itself* only applies to value resolvers, member value resolvers, type converters etc. Unrelated to what you need. You want:

```
CreateMap<Entity.BobEF, IBob>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
```

That will also cause you destination objects to be constructed the same way.
But I have to agree with  @JoepVerhoeven, it sounds like over-engineering.

Comment: You both maybe right. I haven't programmed for a long time and frameworks, standards and practices have moved on substantially since my code monkey days. My understanding of DI however, leads me to believe that models used by the forms/views needs to be implementations of an interfaces, and subsequently complex types exposed through properties should be exposed via their associated interfaces. In this manner anything can be replaced in the testing process as long as it also implements the same interface. Is this not correct ? I'll modify the original post to include an example

Comment: The class examples for IProduct (above) has a property of type ISupplier so I have to create a mapping for [ this.CreateMap<Entity.Supplier, ISupplier>() ] because that's the Type that automapper will see and try to map to.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why automapper returns a Proxy object is because you are mapping a class to an interface and automapper does not know which implementation of `IBob` to use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however the link to the example is quite the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve, as I want my concrete classes to be returned. Automapper doesn't have to know what the implementation is for IBob as we've given it a reference to a service that does know and can instantiate the concreate objects as and when needed. This was done via this line ...

ConstructServicesUsing(type => container.GetInstance(type));

Comment: Hi @Tim  is it really necessary to use an interface like ``IBob``. Because most of the use cases for automapper is to map Dto objects to domain objects and or domain objects to viewmodels or api responses.  What is your use case or reason the map from an entity framework model to an interface  and why not map to an actual implementation of that interface instead?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Lucian Bargaoanu is correct, but this has required a combination of both `ConstructServicesUsing`  and `ConstructUsingServiceLocator`. I had read the documentation here .. [enter link description here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) but hadn't understood this mean that we should utilise the additional `ConstructUsingServiceLocator` on the mapping declarations.

Example:

```
// Or marker types for assemblies:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // pass the reference into the constructor service.
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => container.GetInstance(type));

    //cfg.ConstructServicesUsing()
    cfg.AddProfile(new BusinessModelsConfig(this.Repository.Context));
});
```

This config is contained within the BusinessModelsConfig ..

```
// mapping definition for product buy
this.CreateMap<Entity.ProductBuy, IProductBuy>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.UniqueIdentifier, option => option.MapFrom(source => source.ProductBuyID))
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Status, option => option.MapFrom(source => source.BuyStatus))
    .ForMember(destination => destination.TimeStamp, option => option.MapFrom(source => source.ts))
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
```

For those needing to also map back to the entities so that change can be reflected within the persistence layer, [this article](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/) proved invaluable in understanding how this can be achieved, although automapper may not be the best tool for this. This article is rather old and I would welcome any information which offers a different perspective.

Comment: Obviously :)  I mean how else it could possibly work? My point was that `ConstructServicesUsing` _by itself_ only applies to services, not to destination objects.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It does seem redundant, but perhaps it will help the next guy.